# Tinybox does not run (eval) javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am using Tinybox (http://www.scriptiny.com/2009/05/javascript-popup-box/) for my popup operations.

Although, when I load a page in the popup and have a script tag in it, it does not work.

Anyidea how I can fix this ?

e.g

```
<script>
  alert('hello world');
</script>
```

Comment: script tags do not get evaluated.

Comment: I think there is too little amount of information about the problem. Maybe you can create example to JSFiddle or paste some source code here?

Answer (score 0):

Tinybox uses innerHTML property of the existing DOM element to insert the result of the ajax request. That is why the script tags are not executed. Read carefully the following topic [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml) and modify the script correspondingly.

For example, like this.. insert in the tinybox.js `eval(c);` after `b.innerHTML=c;` parts. Or you can follow other recommendations given by the link above.